# Set path for favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png

Tags: files

I would like my favicon.ico to be accessible by http://example.com/favicon.ico and http://example.com/apple-touch-icon.png, but I can't manage that.
I tried few things, but nothing helped. My favicon.ico/apple-touch-icon.png is located in the theme root folder.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a symlink, I typically keep my main favicon in my root theme folder, and then in the terminal navigate to the site root and symlink to that icon

```
ln -s PATH/TO/THEME/favicon.ico
```

it makes the most sense to me to keep my theme assets in my theme directory, but then I also like to have the same favicon accessible from the doc-root as well

Answer (score 0):

Use Sumit Madan's answer for favicon.

You can put the touch-icon in the files folder too. And edit yourtheme's template.php

Put this:

```
  $appleIcon = array('#tag' => 'link', '#attributes' => array('href' => '/sites/default/files/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png', 'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon', 'type' => 'image/png'),);
  drupal_add_html_head($appleIcon, 'apple-touch-icon');
```

inside

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally just do a .htaccess Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ /actual/path/to/favicon.ico
```

and same for apple touch icon

Answer (score -1):

Just place your image in root folder and add the path as in screenshot :

[image]